# Sweet Alert Delete Confirmation with a href

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

Im using PHP, and Sweet alert for a delete confirmation. Problem is that it is deleting before showing the sweet alert.

This is my HTML(which is using PHP in it).

```
<div class="delete"><a onclick="return confirmation()" href="'.URLROOT.'/dashboards/delete_note/'.htmlspecialchars($note->note_id).'/'.$data['table'] .'"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>
```

This is my sweet alert

```
function confirmation() {
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

}

The problem is, its not showing the sweet alert, its just going straight to the URL. Do I need to do a form and prevent submits or something like that?

Comment: ev.target.offsetParent.children[0].href <---- for anyone else with a problem this is the way to get the URL that PHP printed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that click on anchor element has a default behavior. You could use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the redirection and navigate manually based on you logic with `window.location.href='url'`

```
<div class="delete">
   <a onclick="confirmation(event)" href="'.URLROOT.'/dashboards/delete_note/'.htmlspecialchars($note->note_id).'/'.$data['table'] .'">
     <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

and in js

```
function confirmation(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var urlToRedirect = ev.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'); //use currentTarget because the click may be on the nested i tag and not a tag causing the href to be empty
console.log(urlToRedirect); // verify if this is the right URL
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  // redirect with javascript here as per your logic after showing the alert using the urlToRedirect value
  if (willDelete) {
    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for showing the message. But I face the problem that every URL is unique because they contain the user_id from PHP. I cant generate PHP with Js

Comment: @James you can get the href value and store it in some variable and use it to redirect. Will update the answer now.

Comment: @James feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem (the grey tick below the voting arrows) for future reference

Comment: Its now redirecting to null, is that because it cant read the PHP maybe?

Comment: try currentTarget and check the url by console.log. Updated code above

Comment: after messing with the console.log I found where the href was. ev.target.offsetParent.children[0].href , and with your code it works perfect. Thanks alot man, this was my first stack question and it was great haha thanks.

Comment: Happy to help @James

Answer (score 0):

You can add the value `javascript:` in the href attribute, like this

```
<a href = 'javascript:
    swal({
  title: "Delete selected item?",
  text: "Unrecoverable Data",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: "true",
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
   swal({ title: "Delete Data Successfully",
 icon: "success"}).then(okay => {
   if (okay) {
    window.location.href = "";
  }
});
    
  } else {
    swal({
    title: "Data Not Deleted",
     icon: "error",
    
    });
  }
});'
class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the href from the link and only handle the link when user click confirmed in the SweetAlert script.

```
<div class="delete"><a onclick="return confirmation()"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>
```

In your javascript:

```
function confirmation() {
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {

    // TODO: Handle your delete url by ajax
    // ...

    swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
      icon: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```